# React how to trigger form submit on input blur?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, onblur

I'm trying to make use of the HTML5 `<input type="email" />` validation check.

I can get it working fine doing this:

```
<form>
  <input type="email" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This gets the validation to work on clicking the sumbit button. However I'd like to trigger the form to submit upon having my `email` field blur.

How do I trigger the form without a submit button `onBlur`?

Like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="email" onBlur={/* trigger form submission */} />
</form>
```

Alternatively, is there a better approach to performaning the HTML5 email validation check upon input blur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `ref` attribute on your form and call the submit function:

```
<form ref="myForm">
  <input type="email" onBlur={this.submitForm.bind(this)} />
</form>
```

Add a function:

```
submitForm(){
  this.refs['myForm'].submit()
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Really appreciate the quick and simple answer!

Comment: If you are using the latest react post v16, better use refs as mentioned in documentation here: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I've actually run into a problem. I get `submit` is not defined.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I got the same. How did you resolve?

Answer (score 2):

use the native `checkValidity` method

```
<form>
  <input type="email" id="a" />
</form>

const a = document.querySelector('#a')


a.addEventListener('blur', e => {
const isValid =  e.target.checkValidity()
console.log(isValid)
})
```

Comment: oh didn't notice you'r using react. to access the DOM, use ref's instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've gone with Manav's answer

Comment: this works for validating and generating validation error message, but how can I show the validation error tooltip?