# Submitting a redux-form using a function

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a form with `handleSubmit`.

```
<form 
   className="side-list-content add-payment" 
 onSubmit={handleSubmit ? handleSubmit : this.alertAddPayment(syncErrors)}

>
</form>
```

Now `onSubmit` I am calling a function like below.

```
    render(){
    const handleSubmit = this.props
    return(
    <form 
       className="side-list-content add-payment" 
     onSubmit={handleSubmit ? handleSubmit : this.alertAddPayment(syncErrors)}      
    >
    </form>
  )
    }
    formVal(){
    if(condition){
        //validating fields
     }
    else{
        //Submit the form
      }
    }
```

Now I tried like this

```
render(){
const handleSubmit = this.props
return(
<form 
   className="side-list-content add-payment" 
 onSubmit = { (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   this.formVal()}}

>
</form>
)
}
```

And in the else part of `formVal()` I tried this

```
formVal(){
if(condition){
    //validating fields
 }
else{
    handleSubmit ? handleSubmit : this.alertAddPayment(syncErrors)//Submit the form
  }
```

But it is not working. How can I submit the form using the function `formVal()`?

Comment: You could work with a ref, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52665647/8350676)

Comment: It's not working with ref

Comment: Your second block of code is unclear and looks invalid, you should have a `return` in `render` and we don't know where `formVal()` is called. Could you take some time to clarify that ?

Comment: Edited the question. Kindly check

Comment: Does my answer help ?

Answer (score 0):

First it looks like you have an error, here you assign all your props to `handleSubmit` :

```
const handleSubmit = this.props
```

If you want to extract only the function it should be:

```
const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
const handleSubmit = this.props.handleSubmit;
```

Then, `reduxForm` gives you a `submit` function in props, so you can do :

```
this.props.submit();
```

See documentation here : https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-submit-promise-code-